# How to modify git log pretty format to strip out certain characters (like commas) from one of the fields?

Tags: bash, git, sed

I have a bash script that creates a CSV file with the git logs for a set of subdirectories across some repos, using git log's --pretty format to put each commit on one line with a few variables from my script as well as some of the built-in options.

The basic format of --pretty I'm using is as follows:

```
git log --pretty="$PWD,${current_dir},%h,%cs,%cN,%s"
```

Within the bash script, the full line looks like:

```
(git log --no-merges --after="${number_of_days} days ago" --pretty="$PWD,${current_dir},%h,%cs,%cN,%s" -- "$current_dir") >> "$starting_dir"/export.csv
```

Here's an example of what the CSV looks like:

```
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,bdacd7e,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message,with,extra,commas,in it
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,45cb4a0,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message foo
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,9f8294b,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message bar
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,3e91e92,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message baz
```

This works fine most of the time, but of course commas in the %s messes up the formatting when the CSV is opened in Excel. What I'd like to have it do instead is replace any commas in %s with a space, so it would look like this:

```
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,bdacd7e,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message with extra commas in it
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,45cb4a0,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message foo
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,9f8294b,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message bar
/path/to/parent,./NameOfSubdirectory,3e91e92,2021-03-24,kclemson,commit message baz
```

What is the right way to do this? I assume I need to pass it to sed, but I'm looking for help on both the sed syntax to swap in a " " for a "," in that field, and also how to do that within the bash script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `,` use some other delimiter that is unlikely to occur in the subject, like `^^^`. Replace `,` with a white space first, and then replace `^^^` with `,`.

```
git log --pretty="$PWD^^^${current_dir}^^^%h^^^%cs^^^%cN^^^%s" | \
    sed -e 's/,/ /g' | sed -e 's/\^^^/,/g'
```

Comment: Brilliant! One of the things I kept getting stuck on was how to pass only %s to sed, your solution is much cleaner and easier to read. Thank you very much.